# How to hash CSS class names in Angular 2 (4) using Webpack 2?

Tags: angular, webpack

I saw on Google News that Google hashes their CSS class names.

[Google News Hashed Class Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYPmG.png)

So i searched how Google did this and found a tutorial, how to hash the class names via Webpack, but in React.

Here is the tutorial how to do it in React: https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/07/css-modules-webpack-react/

I wonder if this is possible in Angular with Webpack, too.

Comment: Please point us to the tutorial. What do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @torazaburo I've added the tutorial. I wan't to use this for more client security.

Comment: @Prolativ How does hashing your CSS classes have **ANY** effect on 'security'

Comment: The hashing doesn't help in security at all, hashing stuff doesn't make them secure. And angular has viewEncapsulation or shadow dom emulation

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would want to hash classes, is to avoid similar classes overwriting each other. In react it makes sense to do so, because as far as I am aware there is not any form of style encapsulation in react (I could be completely wrong on this one).

This is something you don't need to worry about in Angular in case you are going to be building components without turning off the `viewEncapsulation`. Angular will take care of ensuring similar class names don't clash (or "leak").

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tynxud) of that on stackblitz.

Please notice how I defined two classes with the same name and different values, angular prefixes them to ensure they are unique to every component.

Here is a demonstration of what I mean in the demo

[image: angular viewencapsulation]

If you would like to read more on Angular's view encapsulation, I would recommend you to check out [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) article by thoughtram.

Comment: Is not the only reason. Angular default encapsulation can generate a css bundle bigger. Using hashes, it can reduce the bundle size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hash the CSS class names you can do it with [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

I was able to implement [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in an Angular application that uses webpack (no [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)) thanks to [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules).

[postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) hash all the styles, then [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) replaces the class names on the html files by the hashed class names.

In order to use [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) you need to configure your rules for (css|scss|sass) and html files like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'posthtml-loader',
                    options: {
                    config: {
                        ctx: {
                                include: {...options},
                                content: {...options}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
            use: [
                'to-string-loader',                  
                'css-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: () => {
                            return [require("postcss-modules")({generateScopedName: "[hash:base64:8]"})]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
...
```

The [posthtml-loader](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-loader) will search for the `posthtml.config.js` file in the root of the project:

```
module.exports = ({ file, options, env }) => {
    return ({
        plugins: [
            require('posthtml-css-modules')(file.dirname.concat('/').concat(file.basename.replace('.html', '.scss.json')))
        ]
    })
};
```

With that, you should be able to use CSS Modules in Angular with Webpack.

**CSS Modules in Angular (with Angular CLI)**

You can use CSS Modules in Angular with Angular CLI too.

The approach is the same, the only difference is that you need to use [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) to customize the build so you can add [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules).

I documented CSS Modules in Angular (with Angular CLI) here:

- Live Demo: https://angular-css-modules.herokuapp.com/
- Github Repo: https://github.com/gquinteros93/angular-css-modules
- Article with the step by step: https://indepth.dev/angular-css-modules/

I hope it will be useful for you.